# Error: SSL connect error on Insomnia when trying to make a localhost request

Tags: node.js, reactjs, frontend, backend, insomnia

Usually when creating a BaseUrl in Environments or defining the request url to test the API the developer ends up forgetting and **putting Https: // instead of putting Http: //** for a local test. So the SSL connect error happens, just set to http and test.

Answer (score 12):

I also run in to same problem and fix it by changing `https` with `http`

Answer (score 0):

you can either choose to ignore ssl verification from your api explorer (`insomnia` can, not sure about the others), or give your application a self signed certificate to enable `HTTPS` in your local web app